# Linked List natural mergeSort

Tags: java

So **Natural mergeSort** is a variation on mergeSort that instead of splitting the list into halves, you iterate through the list, make 2 new temp lists that are "naturally sorted" and then sort those 2 lists. 
**e.g. List = 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, null**

The **first temp list == 1, 3** because 1 < 3, but 3 is not < 2
The **second temp list == 2, 4, 5**

Next step is to compare first temp list with second temp list

```
if( firstTemp > secondTemp) 
     swap;
```

My problem comes from creating these 2 separate lists. 
When I create the 2 new lists, it's erasing my original list. Also I can't seem to get my counter right for creating the size of the lists. A new list doesn't seem to act like a new list because the counter keeps incrementing from the original list to the new lists.
Like the e.g. above,

> **ogList.size = 5**
>   then
>   **firstTemp.size = 7**
>   **secondTemp.size = 10**

When it should be

> **firstTemp.size = 2**
>   and
>   **secondTemp.size = 3**

```
package mergesortlinkedlist;

public class MergeSortLinkedList {

static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //
    // start linked list
    //
    LinkedList.push(list, 1);
    LinkedList.push(list, 3);
    LinkedList.push(list, 2);
    LinkedList.push(list, 4);
    LinkedList.push(list, 5);


    list.printList(list);


    System.out.println("list size = " + list.head.getCounter());

    naturalMerge(list);

}

public static void naturalMerge(LinkedList front) {
    LinkedList set1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList set2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList temp = front;

    //get first temp list
    while (temp != null) {

        if (temp.head.data < temp.head.next.data) {
            LinkedList.push(set1, temp.head.data);
            temp.head = temp.head.next;

        } else {
            LinkedList.push(set1, temp.head.data);
            temp.head = temp.head.next;
            break;

        }
    }

    //get second temp list
    while (temp != null) {

        if (temp.head.data < temp.head.next.data) {
            LinkedList.push(set2, temp.head.data);
            temp.head = temp.head.next;
        } else {
            LinkedList.push(set2, temp.head.data);
            temp.head = temp.head.next;
            break;

        }
    }

    mergeSwap(set1, set2);
}


public static void mergeSwap(LinkedList set1, LinkedList ){   

    //template code to swap the naturally sorted temp lists
    }
 }
}



public class LinkedList {

public Node head;

public static class Node {

    public Node next = null;
    public Integer data;
    public static int counter = 0;

    Node() {

    }

    Node(int d) {
        this.data = d;
    }

    public void setCounter(int n) {
        counter += n;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}

public static void push(LinkedList list, int data) {
    // Create a new node with given data 
    Node new_node = new Node(data);
    new_node.next = null;

    // If the Linked List is empty, 
    // then make the new node as head 
    if (list.head == null) {
        list.head = new_node;
        new_node.setCounter(1);

    } else {
        // Else traverse till the last node 
        // and insert the new_node there 
        Node last = list.head;
        while (last.next != null) {
            last = last.next;
        }

        // Insert the new_node at last node 
        last.next = new_node;
        new_node.setCounter(1);

    }

    // Return the list by head 
    //return list; 
}
```

I'm just wondering if this version of my code is possible for creating separate lists for natural mergeSort. Am I able to use this code to make new lists without destroying the original list?

Ultimately, I want my list = 1,2,3,4,5,null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I changed some things, it's not able to do recurssive calls, which makes me think the logic isn't working right, but I'm still able to sort the list.
Instead of calling

```
naturalMerge(list);
```

after swapping nodes, I do it from main. The only reason is because for some reason I get a null pointer exception.
I'd like to come back to this and make it work better, but for now it'll probably do for getting my assignment turned in.

```
package mergesortlinkedlist;

public class MergeSortLinkedList {

    // static Node first = new Node();
    static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start linked list
        list.add(list, 1);
        list.add(list, 5);
        list.add(list, 3);
        list.add(list, 4);
        list.add(list, 2);
        list.add(list, 100);
        list.add(list, 76);
        list.add(list, -6);

        list.printList(list);

        naturalMerge(list);

        list.printList(list);

        naturalMerge(list);

        list.printList(list);

        naturalMerge(list);

        list.printList(list);

    }

    public static void naturalMerge(LinkedList front) {
        LinkedList set1 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList set2 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList temp = front;
        int size1 = 0;
        int sortCounter = 0;        //if sortCounter != 0, then there is more to sort

        //get first temp list
        while (temp.head.data != null) {

            if (temp.head.data < temp.head.next.data) {

                set1.add(set1, temp.head.data);
                size1++;
                temp.head = temp.head.next;

            } else {
                set1.add(set1, temp.head.data);
                size1++;
                temp.head = temp.head.next;
                break;

           }
        }

        //get second temp list
        while (temp.head != null) {

            if (temp.head.next == null) {
                set2.add(set2, temp.head.data);
                temp.head = temp.head.next;
                break;
            }
            if (temp.head.data < temp.head.next.data) {

                set2.add(set2, temp.head.data);

                temp.head = temp.head.next;

            } else {

                set2.add(set2, temp.head.data);

                temp.head = temp.head.next;

                break;

            }
        }

        mergeSwap(set1, set2, size1);
    }

    public static void mergeSwap(LinkedList set1, LinkedList set2, int size1)  {

        System.out.println();
        LinkedList temp = set1;
        LinkedList temp2 = set2;


        while (temp.head != null && temp2.head != null) {

            if (temp.head.data < temp2.head.data) {

                list.add(list, temp.head.data);
                temp.head = temp.head.getNext();    //increment temp

            } else {

                list.add(list, temp2.head.data);
                temp2.head = temp2.head.getNext();  //increment temp2

            }

            //if one list is empty, break loop and add remaining nodes
            if (temp.head == null || temp2.head == null) {
               break;
            }

        }
        //check which list is empty, and add the remaining nodes to original list
        if (temp.head == null) {
            while (temp2.head != null) {
               list.add(list, temp2.head.data);
               temp2.head = temp2.head.getNext();
           }
        } else {
            while (temp.head != null) {
               list.add(list, temp.head.data);
               temp.head = temp.head.getNext();
            }
        }

        //naturalMerge(list);     //this call breaks the code, but why? How is it any different from the method call in main?
    }
}
```